# Vector Spaces - Graphs and Networks

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The previous problem is this: For the $3$-node triangular graph in the figure following, write the $3$ by $3$ incidence matrix $A$. Find a solution to $Ax = 0$ and describe all other vectors in the nullspace of $A$. Find a solution to $A^{\top}y = 0$ and describe all other vectors in the left nullspace of $A$.

[Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XYMQ.png)

Answer to this is here : [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbooB.png)

My problem: For the same $3$ by $3$ matrix, show directly from the columns that every vector $b$ in the column space will satisfy $b_1 + b_2 - b_3 = 0$. Derive the same thing from the three rows—the equations in the system $Ax = b$. What does that mean about potential differences around a loop?

I could not understand the problem and not sure how to solve it. Could you help me with that?

Thank you for any effort.

Comment: You did not paste the first part of your homework question.

Comment: Can you check it again?

Comment: @MathLover I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Write the equation in the problem a little differently: the problem is asking you to show that the column space $\mathcal C(A)$ of $A$ is the solution space of the equation $x+y-z=0$. To show this, use the fact that $\mathcal C(A)=\mathcal N(A^T)^\perp$, i.e., for all $\mathbf n\in\mathcal N(A^T)$ and $\mathbf b\in\mathcal C(A)$, $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf b=0$. You found a basis for $\mathcal N(A^T)$ in the first part, so what does the above dot product look like when expanded in terms of coordinates? Similar considerations apply to the row space of $A$.